# Erlang supervisor termination behavior

Tags: erlang, terminate, erlang-supervisor

I have what may be an unusual situation, an application that starts 2 top-level supervisors, e.g.,

```
...
-behavior(application).
...
start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    sup1:start_link(),
    sup2:start_link().
```

They both have a `{one_for_one, 0, 1}` restart strategy.  Their children implement a simple `crash` function that throws a bad_match error.

To my question, if I call `sup1_child1:crash()` supervisor `sup1` will terminate but the application will keep running (i.e., supervisor `sup2` and its children are still available).  If instead I call `sup2_child1:crash()` then the entire application terminates.  This latter behavior is what I expect in both cases.  If I flip the order of the `start_link()` calls, i.e.,

```
...
    sup2:start_link(),
    sup1:start_link().
```

then crashing sup1 will cause the application to terminate but crashing sup2 will not.  So it appears the order in which start_link() is called determines which supervisor crash will cause the application to terminate.  Is this expected?  Or am I abusing the supervision tree capability by having 2 root supervisors?

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely expected, and it is expected **because** you are abusing the supervision tree capability. There is a hidden supervisor called the "application supervisor". Your application:start function is supposed to return a SINGLE pid which is to be monitored by the application supervisor. If that process crashes, the BEAM VM will also crash (depending, actually, on how the application is started; similar to worker processes, your applications can be permanent or transient (maybe even temporary)).

You should have one top-level supervisor (**your** application supervisor). If you need two supervisors at the top level, they should both be children of **your** application supervisor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I poked around some more and found this statement in the [Erlang OTP Principles Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id73655) - _start is called when starting the application and should create the supervision tree by starting the top supervisor. It is expected to return the pid of the top supervisor and an optional term State, which defaults to []. This term is passed as-is to stop._  Pretty much what you said.  Thanks again!